# Windows DNS Server (2012 R2): SRVFAIL ("Server Failure") when resolving it's own hostname

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-dns, srvfail

I don't know if this matters, but I'm troubleshooting a LOB that's crashing intermittently, so why not dig into the ol' DNS on WireShark?

I'm seeing regular (like every few minutes) "Server Failure" (`SRVFAIL`) replies back to the client, for A record requests for the actual DNS server's hostname `MAINSERVER`.  This is a small environment with a single DC/server (Essentials 2012 R2).

There exists an A record for `MAINSERVER`, as expected.  There are no other SRVFAILs for any other DNS record requested, so it's not a load issue.

I doesn't appear to be related to DNSSEC, as I've attempted to disable/restart DNS server service with no effect.  It is only for the server's A record, nothing else.

I don't suspect that the DNS suffix (which is correct anyways) is at play here on the client-side, but I'm curious as to why/what is happening on the server-side.